# self-define kernel for matrix multiplication in CUDA

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

I am just starting CUDA programming and I am learning something on kernel design for matrix multiplication. I copy the main code found online and I have added my part to implement matrix multiplication of A(MxM) and B(MxN)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <cusp/complex.h>

using namespace std;

const int M=55, N=73;

typedef cusp::complex<double> Complex;

__global__ void kernelFunc(Complex* ad, Complex* bd, Complex* cd, int n) 
{
  int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
  int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

  if(x < n && y < n) 
  {   
    Complex v = Complex(0.0, 0.0);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) v += ad[y * n + i] * bd[i * n + x];
    cd[y * n + x] = v;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector< Complex > _A(M*M);
  std::vector< Complex > _B(M*N);
  Complex *A, *B, *C;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&A, M*M*sizeof(Complex));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&B, M*N*sizeof(Complex));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&C, M*N*sizeof(Complex));

  for (int i=0; i<M*M; i++) _A[i] = Complex((double)i, (double)i);
  for (int i=0; i<M*N; i++) _B[i] = Complex(1.0, 0.0);

  cudaMemcpy( A, &_A[0], (M*M)*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
  cudaMemcpy( B, &_B[0], (M*N)*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  dim3 block(32, 32);           
  dim3 grid((M+31)/32, (M+31)/32);

  kernelFunc<<<grid, block>>>(A, B, C, M);
  cudaMemcpy(&_B[0], &C[0], (M*N)*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaFree(A);
  cudaFree(B);
  cudaFree(C);

  return 0;
}
```

But it stated online that the involved matrices must be square matrices so does it mean that this code cannot be used on matrices of arbitrary dimension?
I don't understand how to define the number of blocks and number of grids to fit my problem. The matrix in my problem has dimension MxM with M an odd number. I try above code for small matrix, it seems work but I have to apply that to pretty big matrix. 
I don't know if that will work for big matrix too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given code is applicable to square matrices only. A little modification is required to make it generalized. The kernel may be modified as follows:

```
__global__ void kernelFunc(Complex* ad, Complex* bd, Complex* cd, int m1, int n1, int n2) 
{
  int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
  int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

  if(x < n2 && y < m1) 
  {   
    Complex v = Complex(0.0, 0.0);
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++) v += ad[y * n1 + i] * bd[i * n2 + x];
    cd[y * n2 + x] = v;
  }
}
```

Where `m1` is rows of first matrix, `n1` is columns of 1st matrix and `n2` is columns of second matrix. The grid size will be modified accordingly as:

```
dim3 grid((N+31)/32, (M+31)/32);
```

And finally, the kernel call:

```
kernelFunc<<<grid, block>>>(A, B, C, M, M, N);
```